# How can one develop a mobile app using Django at the back-end and React native with Vue js at the front-end?

Tags: javascript, python, mobile, mobile-application

I'm new to mobile app development and we want to develop a mobile app using Django. I and a friend of mine thought of using Django at the backend, PostgresSQL as the database, and React native and vue js at the front-end.
What do you guys think about it? Any tips for extreme beginners?
Just tell me in any way you think we can do this or a source that can help us.

**For more details about the mobile app:**
Briefly, the app is a budget management system. It will be about creating a budget, its expenses, calculating the budget amount, and notifying the user when the deadline for the budget is closer.

Comment: Please review what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic]. This question is primarily opinion-based and way too broad. Having said that, why do you want to use React Native _and_ Vue.js? Pick one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really think if you can actually directly way do that. ***Django is a server side web framework.*** But you can user some third party to make the mobile application. like one I personally know is [Go Native](https://gonative.io).

You can create a website as usual and need to host that website and now you are hosting that website. Go to Go Native and it will ask for the URL of your website, some other things as well. Give URL and It will provide `.apk`(Mobile application).

You may find may many things to making website to `apk` this I gave is just an example. Or if you know Java then you can create on your own. [Here's](https://medium.com/@hassanabid/developing-android-client-app-with-django-rest-framework-8d5961a49619) the helping link for you.

Answer (score 1):

In order to provide accurate references or more details, a more in-depth description should be added as to what type of app you want to create, the objective, use case, demographic etc.

However, with such a broad question of "how to develop an app on django", heading over to google, youtube, and medium to start digging in will help you narrow down your concept. There's plenty of tutorials and examples available, and with more 'key words' such as "developing a social media app on django', search results will be improved.

Lastly, when that first research stage is complete, then it's easier to come back to stackoverflow with a more specific question, details about what you've already tried, and specific problems you need to solve.

Comment: Sure, thank you so  much for the advice. Well, I updated the question and I hope everything is clear now.